# How to enforce unique 2-tuple on oracle table?

Tags: database, oracle, constraints, unique

I am trying to enforce the property that table Match should have all unique tuples (Team 1, Team 2).  However, let Team 1 = Detroit Pistons and Team 2 = Chicago Bulls.  I do not want to allow (Detroit Pistons, Chicago Bulls) to be inserted into the table if (Chicago Bulls, Detroit Pistons) already exists.

How can I enforce this constraint?

Comment: A trigger is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique function-based index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_match ON match ( LEAST(team1,team2), GREATEST(team1,team2) );
```

`LEAST()` will get the "lesser" of the two teams (whether by ID or name, it doesn't matter) while `GREATEST` will get the "greater" of the two. Unfortunately this particular solution doesn't scale up to 3-or-more-tuples.

Answer (score 4):

A) The tuples are semantically identical. (I think this is your case.)

That means the tuple {Chicago Bulls, Detroit Pistons} means exactly the same thing as the tuple {Detroit Pistons, Chicago Bulls}. Use a CHECK constraint to impose an order on the two columns.

```
CHECK (column_1 < column_2)
```

That kind of constraint would allow {Chicago Bulls, Detroit Pistons}, but it would reject {Detroit Pistons, Chicago Bulls}. This is kind of like imposing a canonical form on otherwise free-form data.

B) The tuples are semantically distinct.

That means the tuple {Chicago Bulls, Detroit Pistons} means one thing, and the tuple {Detroit Pistons, Chicago Bulls} means something else. For example, the first attribute might mean "home team", and the second might mean "visiting team". In this case, all you need is some kind of unique constraint on the pair of columns.